# Select rows with part duplicate rows Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to capture a specific subset of data using Spark Scala
I am partly able to accomplish it, but looking for guidance here.

The data looks like this:

| Member_id | Start_Date | End_Date | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 20220101 | 20221201 | Prod1 |
| abcd | 20220101 | 20230201 | Prod2 |
| efgh | 20220101 | 20221201 | Prod1 |
| efgh | 20220101 | 20230201 | Prod1 |
| ijkl | 20220201 | 20230201 | Prod1 |
| mnop | 20220501 | 20221201 | Prod1 |
| mnop | 20220501 | 20230201 | Prod2 |
| qrst | 20220501 | 20230201 | Prod2 |

In this, I want to capture the **abcd** member_id and **mnop** member_id because they have the same start_date, but different product.

My ultimate goal is to adjust the start and end_date and make them not overlap. (That is not the question for this issue right now)

So far I have tried using row_number window function, but when I use row_number >1 , it ends up capture the member_id **efgh** as well:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("member_id", "start_date").orderBy("end_date")

val abc = sqlContext.table("members")
.withColumn("row_number",row_number.over(window))
.filter(col("row_number")>1)
```

I think using a distinct count somehow would be helpful, but unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a window function here. Usually, you'd use window functions when you want an output for every row. Since you want to operate on groupings of `member_id` and `start_date`, you can use a `groupBy` and aggregate on that. I ran your example in `spark-shell`:

```
val testDF = Seq(
("abcd",20220101,20221201,"Prod1"),
("abcd",20220101,20230201,"Prod2"),
("efgh",20220101,20221201,"Prod1"),
("efgh",20220101,20230201,"Prod1"),
("ijkl",20220201,20230201,"Prod1"),
("mnop",20220501,20221201,"Prod1"),
("mnop",20220501,20230201,"Prod2"),
("qrst",20220501,20230201,"Prod2")
).toDF("member_id", "start_date", "end_date", "product")

testDF.groupBy("member_id", "start_date")
.agg(countDistinct("product").as("distinct_products"))
.filter(col("distinct_products") > 1)
.show
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|member_id|start_date|distinct_products|
+---------+----------+-----------------+
|     abcd|  20220101|                2|
|     mnop|  20220501|                2|
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Right, I figured this out as well. But I want to retain the end_date as well in my output, and perhaps the other fields in the data.

Comment: Retain the other fields in what format? If you want them in the same row, you can use `collect_list("end_date")` to get a list of the associated end dates.