# Compare 2 dataframes using scala and in case of duplicates, compare rows just once

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have 2 dataframes with many columns, that I compare using 3 columns to create matches: col1, col2, col3 and sometimes there are duplicates, like in the example below.
My tool compares the dataframes and is looking for maismatches, but when I compare col4 from df1 with col4 from df2, I'd like to only create the match, so that row1 from df1 === row1 from df2 and stop there, do not compare row1 from df1 with row2 from df2 and then create a mismatch, because there is actually no mismatch, the rows are identical both sides.
Is there any way to accomplish this? After the tool runs, it creates some reports for the mismatches found, and because of the situations when we have duplicates, the reports are not correct.

df1

| col 1 | col2 | col3 | col 4. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A | ABC | 1000 |
| 123456 | A | ABC | 500 |

df2

| col 1 | col2 | col3 | col 4. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A | ABC | 1000 |
| 123456 | A | ABC | 500 |

```
val result = df1.as("df1").join(
  df2.as("df2"),
  expr(s"df1.${key1}=df2.${key1}_ and df1.${key2}=df2.${key2}_ and df1.column_name=df2.column_name_")
)
```

This is the way I'm comparing the dataframes, I'm using 3 keys, not 2 as in this example, but in this case df1.row1 is compared twice, once with df2.row1 and then df2.row2 and this way it creates 1 match and 1 mismatch, but the mismatch is not actually correct.

Comment: could you give an example of the report you want to produce?

Comment: doing a **join** without a **join condition** will produce a cartesian product. Maybe doing a `union` and then with `groupBy` you could do what you want. [Select rows with part duplicate rows Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409418/select-rows-with-part-duplicate-rows-spark-scala) could help

Comment: The report should not contain any mismatch for this specific rows. The rows are identical in both dataframes, but because col1, col2 and col3 are duplicates, there are created mismatches. As I said, df1.row1 is compared twice, once with df2.row1 and then df2.row2 and this way it creates 1 match and 1 mismatch. Same for df1.row2, is compared with df2.row1 and then with df2.row2. I just want to compare df1.row1 with df2.row1 and df1.row2 with df2.row2

Comment: It's not clear for me the expected output with those details. Coud you edit your post and show an example of what is the report you want to produce?